# Grouping same value for each jQuery

Tags: jquery, key, grouping, each

I want to do something like sql **groupBy** but in **jQuery each** .

My Code :

```
$.each(allItems, function (i, val) {
    var itemIconURL = val['itemIcon'];
    var itemIcon = 'http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/' + itemIconURL + '/90fx90f';
    str += '<img src="'+ itemIcon +'"/>';
    console.log('key:' +i+ ', value:' + itemIconURL +'');
});
```

I want to do :

If this same value just display one of this and get number how much grouped.

It needs to group by `itemIconURL`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `counters` hash to count the `itemIconURL`s as the loop progresses, and only create the `<img>` HTML on first occurrence of each `itemIconURL`.

```
var counters = {},
    str = '';
$.each(allItems, function (i, val) {
    var itemIconURL = val['itemIcon'];
    if(!counters[itemIconURL]) {
        counters[itemIconURL] = 1;
        var itemIcon = 'http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/' + itemIconURL + '/90fx90f';
        str += '<img src="' + itemIcon + '"/>';
        console.log('key:' + i + ', value:' + itemIconURL + '');
    } else {
        counters[itemIconURL] += 1;
    }
});
console.log(counters);

// Now do whatever is necessary with the `counters` hash,
// for example, loop through it
$.each(counters, function(key, value) {
    // do something with `key` and/or `value`
});
```

**EDIT**

Reading between the lines, I expect you want something like this :

```
var counters = {},
    str = '';
// First tally up the group counts
$.each(allItems, function (i, val) {
    var itemIconURL = val['itemIcon'];
    if(!counters[itemIconURL]) {
        counters[itemIconURL] = 1;
    } else {
        counters[itemIconURL] += 1;
    }
});
// Now build the HTML
$.each(counters, function(key, value) {
    var itemIcon = 'http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/' + key + '/90fx90f';
    str += '<img src="' + itemIcon + '"/>' + value;
});
$("#someContainer").html(str);
```

Comment: But counters not displaying only number, but whole URL and number, i need to get only number

Comment: What you do with `counters` after the loop has completed is up to you. I just wrote `console.log(counters);` because I didn't know what you wanted to do with the data.

Comment: counters is displaying for example : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8  . And i want to display only last generated number. how?

Comment: See if you can write a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate the symptoms.

Comment: I can't visualise the issue.

Comment: That can't be the result of `console.log(counters);`. Looks more like an array.